# Determining if an association between two models has been created within one model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been researching this topic for a day now, and I haven't seen a solution that could adequately allow this. I would have even give up and said that it's not possible, but I see large companies achieving this in their apps!

I need to know if the current user is following another user. I need to know this many times (for the current_user) without polling the DB again

The solution needs to be friendly for reuse. A solution (that's not friendly for reuse) I had come up with is as follows:

```
module UsersHelper
    def is_following?(user)
        return false if current_user == user
        user.is_following = Relationship.find_by(followed_id: user.id, follower_id: current_user.id)
    end
end
```

`is_following?(@user)` can now be called in any controller

Notice that I'm able to access `current_user` because this helper method will be called in a controller, not a model.

This implementation is cool for one model, maybe two... except I need to do this in almost every many-many relationship I have in the app. So it has to be scalable.

I'm referencing exactly what Twitter does with their following.

Comment: Try to describe specific use cases for more clarity. In general this can be solved by structuring the data as a graph - entities are nodes, relations are edges between them. Every node can have n+1 edges connecting them to other nodes.

Comment: I need to know if the current user is following another user. I need to know this many times (for the current_user) without polling the DB again

Comment: maintain the follow graph in memory as a hash, the key is the user_id, and the value is an array of user_ids that the user_id specified in key is following. update the value when user follow/unfollow a user.

Comment: @jsksma2 you can `memoize` `is_following?` such that a call to `is_following?` with the same user object would return the same value,  you might need to use an external cache for this, you can either lookup the railscast or use the [memoist gem](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist)

Comment: What kind of associations do you have set up? If User `has_many :relationships`, then you could do something like `has_many :users, through: :relationships` (a self-referential association), and then simply do `current_user.users.include?(user)`. AR will cache `users` for you like any association. Of course, you could name `users` something more appropriate. Check out the [Railscast on this topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).

Comment: @Jimeux My models are good. Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/Jakenberg/8603642

Comment: `current_user.users.include?(user)` is brilliant, but is it possible to automate the method for scalability? I don't want to have to call that method for every association I have in every method when I load that particular model in a controller.